# JavaScript: function returning an object

Tags: javascript

I'm taking some JavaScript/jQuery lessons at codecademy.com. Normally the lessons provide answers or hints, but for this one it doesn't give any help and I'm a little confused by the instructions.

It says to make the function makeGamePlayer return an object with three keys.

```
//First, the object creator
function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
    //should return an object with three keys:
    // name
    // totalScore
    // gamesPlayed
}
```

I'm not sure if i should be doing this

```
//First, the object creator
function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
    //should return an object with three keys:
    // name
    // totalScore
    // gamesPlayed

         this.name =  name;
         this.totalScore = totalScore;
         this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
}
```

or something like this

```
 //First, the object creator
    function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
        //should return an object with three keys:
        // name
        // totalScore
        // gamesPlayed

         var obj = {
             this.name =  name;
             this.totalScore = totalScore;
             this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
          }
    }
```

I have to be able to modify the properties of the object after its created.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In JavaScript, most [functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects) are both callable and instantiable: they have both a [[[Call]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) and [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) internal methods.

As callable objects, you can use parentheses to call them, optionally passing some arguments. As a result of the call, the function can [return a value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-return-statement).

```
var player = makeGamePlayer("John Smith", 15, 3);
```

The code above calls function `makeGamePlayer` and stores the returned value in the variable `player`. In this case, you may want to define the function like this:

```
function makeGamePlayer(name, totalScore, gamesPlayed) {
  // Define desired object
  var obj = {
    name:  name,
    totalScore: totalScore,
    gamesPlayed: gamesPlayed
  };
  // Return it
  return obj;
}
```

Additionally, when you call a function you are also passing an additional argument under the hood, which determines the value of [`this`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-this-keyword) inside the function. In the case above, since `makeGamePlayer` is not called as a method, the `this` value will be the global object in sloppy mode, or undefined in strict mode.

As constructors, you can use the [`new` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-new-operator) to instantiate them. This operator uses the [[[Construct]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) internal method (only available in constructors), which does something like this:

1. Creates a new object which inherits from the `.prototype` of the constructor
2. Calls the constructor passing this object as the `this` value
3. It returns the value returned by the constructor if it's an object, or the object created at step 1 otherwise.

```js
var player = new GamePlayer("John Smith", 15, 3);
```

The code above creates an instance of `GamePlayer` and stores the returned value in the variable `player`. In this case, you may want to define the function like this:

```
function GamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
  // `this` is the instance which is currently being created
  this.name =  name;
  this.totalScore = totalScore;
  this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
  // No need to return, but you can use `return this;` if you want
}
```

By convention, constructor names begin with an uppercase letter.

The advantage of using constructors is that the instances inherit from `GamePlayer.prototype`. Then, you can define properties there and make them available in all instances

Comment: @OP also note that when you are going to invoke it with the `new` keyword I would suggest starting the name with a capital: `MakeGamePlayer`.

Comment: @PeeHaa Good advice, also the more typical naming convention when using the constructor would be `new GamePlayer()`.

Comment: @RobG Thanks, that's what happens when I copy-paste code without looking at it deeply.

Answer (score 55):

You can simply do it like this with an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

```
function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
    return {
        name: name,
        totalscore: totalScore,
        gamesPlayed: gamesPlayed
    };
}
```

Comment: hello, how can you access the return properties , When I use 
makeGamePlayer.name it doesnt work

Comment: var player1 = makeGamePlayer("Bobby Fischer", 15, 5);
player1.name;

Comment: Does this return a copy of the object or a reference to the object?

Answer (score 12):

The latest way to do this with ES2016 JavaScript

```
let makeGamePlayer = (name, totalScore, gamesPlayed) => ({
    name,
    totalScore,
    gamesPlayed
})
```

Answer (score 7):

Both styles, with a touch of tweaking, would work.

The first method uses a Javascript Constructor, which like most things has pros and cons.

```
 // By convention, constructors start with an upper case letter
function MakePerson(name,age) {
  // The magic variable 'this' is set by the Javascript engine and points to a newly created object that is ours.
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.occupation = "Hobo";
}
var jeremy = new MakePerson("Jeremy", 800);
```

On the other hand, your other method is called the 'Revealing Closure Pattern' if I recall correctly.

```
function makePerson(name2, age2) {
  var name = name2;
  var age = age2;

  return {
    name: name,
    age: age
  };
}
```

Comment: Is called "revealing module pattern" But it is usually wrapped into private closure
(function(){return{}})()

Answer (score 3):

I would take those directions to mean:

```
  function makeGamePlayer(name,totalScore,gamesPlayed) {
        //should return an object with three keys:
        // name
        // totalScore
        // gamesPlayed

         var obj = {  //note you don't use = in an object definition
             "name": name,
             "totalScore": totalScore,
             "gamesPlayed": gamesPlayed
          }
         return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have semicolons inside of object?

Comment: @AlexG nice catch, can't believe no one else did in the 4 years since I first posted this answer. It was undoubtedly a bad cut-n-paste job of the OP's original object that I and it looks like a few others made.