# Curly braces and filters - filter returns object but it gets converted to a string inside {{ }}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am not totally clear on what exactly happens between {{ }}. I understand they evaluate code and return the result. I also noticed that the result is converted to a string by default.

But what if I need the content of {{}} to remain an object?

Here's what I mean:

I have a filter:

```
app.filter('tryme', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return {foo:bar};
    };
});
```

now the following line will display '{foo:bar}' as a string

```
<td>{{ data | tryme}} </td>
```

what I am trying to do is display only the value of foo, so I was hoping something like this could work and render 'bar'

```
<td>{{ somedata | tryme}}['foo'] </td>
```

but no dice... Is it possible to get an object inside curly braces and further reach inside it to render some value?

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272239/javascript-function-returning-an-object)

Comment: what about `{{ data.foo }}`? or you want to work with value from filter

Comment: yeah I needed to work with the value inside that object... I knwe this was possible, just a matter of syntax.. TheSharpieOne's answer nailed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add parens around your statement and then you can access it as an object while within the {{}}

```
{{(data | tryme)['foo']}} 
{{(data | tryme).foo}} also works
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/uJP2c/1/