# Javascript: Function that returns an object containing other functions? What is this called?

Tags: javascript

I am somewhat new to Javascript (been using it for a few months), but overall I would probably consider myself a borderline novice/intermediate programmer. I am now working on a fairly large project in Javascript, containing many different functions, and I am trying to figure out some "best practices" for organizing my code.

I have seen a few examples of an approach that seems potentially very helpful. For example, see [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272260/2917273), or [this page on best practices](http://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices) (do a Ctrl+F for `return{`). Essentially, you define a function in a variable, and that function simply returns other functions/variables:

```
var functionContainer = function() {
    return {
        function1 : function () {
            // Do something
        },

        function2 : function () {
            // Do something else
        }
    };
}();
```

This seems helpful in cases where I have multiple functions that do similar things; I can put them all into a "container" of sorts, and then call them with `functionContainer.function1();`.

Essentially, my question is: **Is there a name for this technique? Can you recommend any sources for further reading?** A lot of sources that I've seen don't go into great depth about what exactly is going on when you do this, and I want to be sure that I fully understand what I'm doing before I start shuffling around a bunch of my code.

I may post some separate follow-up questions later, depending on the responses I get here. If so, I will post links to them here, for anyone else who's curious.

Comment: Revealing Module Pattern.

Comment: As vinoth stated, it is the revealing module pattern:http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Revealing module pattern in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Revealing Module Pattern
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Addy Osmani's Analysis copied from link above:

> Advantages
>
> This pattern allows the syntax of our scripts to be more consistent.
>   It also makes it more clear at the end of the module which of our
>   functions and variables may be accessed publicly which eases
>   readability.
>
> Disadvantages
>
> A disadvantage of this pattern is that if a private function refers to
>   a public function, that public function can't be overridden if a patch
>   is necessary. This is because the private function will continue to
>   refer to the private implementation and the pattern doesn't apply to
>   public members, only to functions.
>
> Public object members which refer to private variables are also
>   subject to the no-patch rule notes above.
>
> As a result of this, modules created with the Revealing Module pattern
>   may be more fragile than those created with the original Module
>   pattern, so care should be taken during usage.

Answer (score 0):

That is just assignment and learning about how in javascript functions are first class types. You also have an object literal as well in there being returned with some functions defined as members. It's kind of like a revealing module pattern though for a proper approach I recommend the following reading: 
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript

Answer (score 0):

This is a just a simple **object literal**. Contrary to some of the other answers, it is not the revealing module pattern. In the revealing module pattern, your functions would be defined in the closure, not in the returned object literal.

However, I think your code is in error. I think you meant to write

```
var functionContainer = (function() {
  return {
    function1 : function () {
        // Do something
    },

    function2 : function () {
        // Do something else
    }
  };
})();
```

With this code, you can call `functionContainer.function1();`. (removed: You could not do that with your original code.) If this pattern is what you meant, then it is an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) returning an object literal.

Comment: _"You could not do that with your original code."_ Of course you could. It's a perfectly valid function expression. You may add the extra parentheses if you wish, but semantically it doesn't make any difference. It's just a visual hook to let the reader know that what's assigned to the variable is the result of the function and not the function itself. Try it out. It works without the parentheses.

Comment: @AaditMShah is correct, thanks. I've modified my answer.