# How can I return an anonymous object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying this:

```
return {
    configs: app.config
}
```

But it does not seem to work. Is there another way to return an anonymous object with the one field "configs" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: function returning an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272239/javascript-function-returning-an-object)

Comment: "It does not seem to work". What does it return? Undefined? An empty object? Does it error? Barring more information, and assuming you're putting in a copy/paste, you'll need to surround "app.config" with quotes, to make it a string.

Comment: You can't have a `return` statement outside of a function. There is nowhere to "return" to.

Comment: The return statement is in a function. When I try to look at the .configs value of what's returned it gives undefined.

Comment: Samantha: then please post the *whole of the relevant code* (because as you've written it, and assuming no errors in the parts we can't see, I would think that *should* work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function someFunc() {
    var retVal = {
        configs: app.config
    };
    return retVal;
}
```

Here is another idea:

```
var someFunc2 = function() { 
    var app = {};
    app.config = 1;
    return { configs: app.config };
};
someFunc2();
// Object {configs: 1}
```

Comment: Why would that work and the OP's code not?

Comment: @Bergi This example worked for me in Chrome: ```x = function() { y = { config: 0}; return { configs: y.config}; } ; x();```

Comment: @Bergi, I'm really not sure.  Maybe a working example or a broader context?